# How do I use maven shade plugin in Eclipse

Tags: java, maven, maven-shade-plugin

I'm a novice here in maven, I'm trying to shade my plugin to add dependencies in my project. But I can't seems to find a way to use maven shade plugin. I would ask that anyone here would show me some examples and explain for me specifically, thanks.

Comment: Can you add some examples of what you've tried?

Comment: I don't understand actually. Do I have to directly create a pom.xml or create a maven project and the thing is pom.xml in eclipse is different from others. Btw I'm using Eclipse Mars. May your guidance lead my way

Comment: If you are using maven then you need a `pom.xml` file. Eclipse will generate one for you, or you can create one from scratch, but for the purpose of your question it doesn't matter.

Comment: As stated I have no idea how to maven shade my java project with adding dependencies so I can load them without noclassdeffounderror.

Answer (score 1):

Generally plugins are added to the `plugins` section of your `pom.xml`. You need to specify the groupId, artifactId, and version of the plugin you are trying to use. For `maven-shade-plugin`, you can import it in your pom like this:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <!-- put your configurations here -->
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

This will bind the goals for the Shade plugin to the `package` phase. Running `mvn package` will produce a shaded JAR.

Source: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/usage.html

You can view more examples in the links at the bottom of this page: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/index.html